# Cannot fully delete jetBrains folder after uninstall?

Tags: intellij-idea, uninstallation, administrator

So i have been using the community edition of intelliJ now for a couple of months with no problems, that is until today, i first noticed that when trying to create and save a new project into my usual folder on the desktop as i have done for countless projects now, it was instead creating some .iml file type within this folder and not a project folder with the name i had specified containing all the usual scr and other folders etc etc, and in the project view instead of seeing my usual package and class (rather small progression of drop downs) there was instead the entire contents of the source folder that i always choose to save all my projects in, i went through a set-up process again of configuring the SDK etc and that is when i noticed that for some reason or another the SDK had been reset to NO SDK!, i thought this might have solved the issue but to no avail the same problem continued even with the SDK set back to what it was previously, it would however let me save projects as i had been doing previously straight onto the desktop in which it would as expected create a project folder with the name of my choosing at the time of creation, and no silly weird never seen before .iml files types, eventually i got tired of the SDK resetting to NO SDK every time i exited the application and also with still be no further forward in figuring out why my projects were no longer saving as they once did i went for the nuclear option and uninstalled, which then brought me to more problems, upon trying to re-install i cannot install it where i would like (which is the jetBrains folder in programs) because the installer tells me i must install to an empty folder, this then led me to realize that the uninstaller had not removed everything, so i navigated to the jetBrains folder in my programs folder to manually delete it in order that i can re-install intelliJ and now im being told "folder access denied" so i cant delete the jetBrains folder as i dont have administrator privileges apparently, which i most certainly do as ive checked my user account (being the only one on the entire system) and it says "administrator", i then went to the properties of the jetBrains folder as well to check and the administrator (i.e. ME) is the owner of that folder, so im now completely stumped, in summary:

- I cant re-install intelliJ, until it has an empty folder.
- I cant empty the folder because i cant delete it.
- I cant delete it because i dont have admin privileges(which i definitely do!).
- And ever if i get all of this sorted none of it guarantees that it will solve the whole problem that started this, the project saving issue, i could still after all this end up with my projects not saving as they have been and the SDK resetting every time exit the application.

Any help with any and all of these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

D.

Edit 1.

My apologies i should have said my OS is Windows 10.

Edit 2.

This would be my normal process for creating a new project:
1. I would select new project.
2. I would then select Java and click next.
3. I would check the box "create project from template" as i had done for untold amounts of projects before today.
4. I would then name my project and click finish.

That was it, that was all i had to do and a new project folder with all its contents was added to my root projects folder which contains all projects ive done in the past 2 months.

Now however, i realized for some reason my projects were not in my usual root folder and were saving in some idea folder in Users/Dave, upon trying to change the saving location back to my usual folder i was presented with a question on whether or not i wished to overwrite the current folder (yes/no), I chose neither of these options as I did not want to overwrite but knowing that the computer would automatically create a new folder if I chose “no”, I did not want this either, I simply wanted it to save the new project I was creating with the name I was defining into the already existing JavaPrograms folder as it had been doing for months, but it just wouldn’t, instead it would create a folder called .idea and in this folder was a bunch of files types and ext of the sort that were not in any other of my individual project folders, at the bottom of the root folder was the .iml file (so was not in the newly created .idea folder), in short it did not matter what newly created project I made and it did not matter what I called it, it was always a .idea folder that was created containing as noted above, and there was always a .iml file created outwith the .idea folder but still within the main root folder, I just don’t understand why this has happened, I was programming last night, went to bed, got up today and THIS!!!!.

Please help.

Comment: Your folder access problem sounds like something still has a lock on it, have you tried restarting your computer? And you seem surprised by the `iml` files, but that's the IntelliJ project file so it's suppose to be there for each project (unless you're on an old version of the IDE?)

Comment: ill try restarting my computer, and while the .iml files may have been there all along they were never front and center(hence my surprise at seeing them), it was always a very simple process.

Comment: Could you try this with [the Toolbox app](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) and see if you run into the same problems with it?

Comment: Ok so tried restarting computer and that didnt change anything, i right clicked on the jetBrains folder and scrolled to properties and changed every single security option to admin privileges and still it tells me that i do not have adim privileges to delete the folder, this is just crazy!, i will try the toolbox and report back thanks.

Comment: If you still can't do anything to the folder, you'll need to [take ownership](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2623670/-access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and) of the folder structure. Also, which [project structure](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/project_structure.html#how-to-work-with-project-files) do you normally use (`.ipr` file vs `.idea/` folder)?

Comment: Ok so i followed the steps to take ownership and was met with this: Error Applying Security An error occured while applying security information to: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community...\Uninstall.exe Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.

Comment: As for project structure, i have no idea, ive only been programming a few months and am following tutorials which up until now have never required me to have an understanding of how my projects are structured, all i know is what ive listed above as the steps i would take to create a project, i have a main root folder with lots and lots of more folders in it each of which is an individual project carrying the name i defined at creation, upon opening a project folder there is a .idea folder, a out folder and a src folder and then the .iml file, it is the same for every individual project folder.

Comment: The issue of admin permissions is resolved, i used unlocker 1.9.2 from majorgeeks and although it couldn't unlock it because it said it wasn't locked, it did however managed to delete the folder for me which was the ultimate goal, now remains the issues of figuring out why my newly created projects are behaving the way they are, hopefully upon re-installation and setup ill be back to where i was last night and will just have to write today off as a loss.

Comment: Ok, so all is well and i after re-installing and going through the tutorials set-up process again, i am now finally back to where i was at this stage last night in that i can create projects which are added to the folder i want automatically, i am still no wiser as to what the hell even happened or why my root location folder changed and why when trying to change it back it had such drastic consequences, i mean its only i file path that i am defining when creating a project you'd think that could have drastic effects on how the program runs but nevertheless it did, anyway its fixed now, thanks

Comment: you'd think that could have drastic effects on how the program runs but nevertheless it did, i meant couldnt have drastic effects not could, its been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

go to properties > security > edit/change > check all access / modify at a bottom checkboxes > apply / ok

open folder jetBrain > delete

restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently dealing with the same issue. I was able to delete the folder after I deleted the cached data from my PC. Delete cache from user >  username > appdata > roaming > jetbrain. I deleted the whole jetbrain file from this directory. Meanwhile, I uninstalled the software before deleting the cache. Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I too faced the above mentioned issue.And I used Unlocker 1.9.2 softwre to delete it.
And this software deleted it successfully.

Comment: Yeah, no. I'm not installing some 3rd party unsigned software with so many false postive reports as adware/malware.